# Using Stripe how can I pass PaymentIntent’s client secret to the form?

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

I would like to add Stripe in my website but I'm noticing that is very difficult to use and there aren't more sources of help in the web.

My first problem is how to Pass the PaymentIntent’s client secret to the client, so how to pass a php variable in my html form.

Before I should create a **PaymentIntent** object:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_8cpWr3HupPdvL9QK9cVToa4w009OYgxfNm');

$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => 0.89,
    'currency' => 'eur',
]);
```

Then `API Stripe` suggest to pass the PaymentIntent’s client secret to the client in this way:

```
<?php
    $intent = # ... Fetch or create the PaymentIntent;
?>
...
<input id="cardholder-name" type="text">
<!-- placeholder for Elements -->
<div id="card-element"></div>
<button id="card-button" data-secret="<?= $intent->client_secret ?>">
  Submit Payment
</button>
...
```

This is page of API: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#passing-to-client

But how can I pass a php variable in html page?

And someone can explain me what is this **client secret**?

Answer (score 1):

The client_secret is a [property of a PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret) that you can use on the frontend with your publishable key.

Based on the example in the Quick Start guide, this is a basic example:

```
<?php
$intent =\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    "amount" => 2000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "payment_method_types" => ["card"],
]);
?>
...
<input id="cardholder-name" type="text">
<!-- placeholder for Elements -->
<div id="card-element"></div>
<button id="card-button" data-secret="<?= $intent->client_secret ?>">
  Submit Payment
</button>
...
```

The key things to note are that you're creating `$intent` in your code, and then echoing `$intent->client_secret` as the proper value in your form later on.

Comment: yes but how can i pass this in my html page ? how can include php file (where i created $intent) in my html page where ther's the form ?